# Notations mentioned in answers re. trombone

Tags: notation

Would someone please explain the notations E2, F3, etc. which are used in answers on this site regarding trombone?  I'm not familiar with those.

Answer (score 3):

It's [Scientific Pitch Notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27322/what-is-the-terminology-for-how-we-identify-numbered-notes-like-c4-e3-d6-etc/27325#27325) that is used to notate the note itself and the octave it is in.

For example E2 tells you that it is specifically the E on the first ledger line under the bass clef.